# independent association between two non-relational / unrelated entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a need to obtain a list of non-relational entity values using a navigational property. In the following model for `FVariable`, I am trying to create a navigation property for maintaining a list of `VariableValue`. How to define an independent association as depicted in the model of `FVariable`:

`public virtual ICollection<VariableValue> Values { get; set; }` ?

The two entities are related through `VariableID` and `DataAttributeCollectionID` properties.

Here is the `FVariable` Entity:

```
public class FVariable
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int FVariableID { get; set; }

    [Index(Unique, Order = 1)]
    public int VariableID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(F.VariableID))]
    public virtual Variable Variable { get; set; }

    [Index(Unique, IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    public int? DataAttributeCollectionID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(FVariable.DataAttributeCollectionID))]
    public virtual DataAttributeCollection DataAttributeCollection { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<VariableValue> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the `VariableValue` entity:

```
public class VariableValue
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int VariableValueID { get; set; }

    [Index(Order = 1)]
    public int VariableID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(VariableValue.VariableID))]
    public virtual Variable Variable { get; set; }

    [Index(Order = 2)]
    public double VariableValue { get; set; }

    public int? DataAttributeCollectionID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(VariableValue.DataAttributeCollectionID))]
    public virtual DataAttributeCollection DataAttributeCollection { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: In EF6, only possible if `VariableID` and `DataAttributeCollectionID` are `FVariable`'s primary key.

Comment: @GertArnold, ah i see so I must have the wrong understanding of independent association. There still must exist a relationship between the entities.